# WinForms progress bar doesn't accurately reflect percent complete

Tags: .net, winforms, progress-bar

I'm using a plain vanilla `System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar` in `.NET 4.7.1`. I'm not doing anything unorthodox, and I'm calling `Application.DoEvents()` after each update to the progress bar. And yet visually, it's way off:

[image]

Notice that Min is 0, Max is 100, Value is 51...and yet the visual progress bar looks like it's at about 20% (value roughly equals 20 out of 100).

*Note: Even when I pause on the debugger after updating the progress bar, it still shows wrong, as in the screenshot above. So it's not a "catching up due to race conditions" issue - it's just plain wrong by a lot. By the time it gets to 100, it jumps to what looks visually like 98 or 99 -- so it's very close but still not fully green.*

What am I missing?

Comment: The related code is missing.  *I'm not doing anything unorthodox* and *I'm calling Application.DoEvents()* don't appear together that often.

Comment: Instead of relying on DoEvents, use a BackgroundWorked to do your file progress, then use the ReportProgress method to avod having to Invoke across threads.

Comment: I believe it is most likely caused by the Application.DoEvents() approach. This only gives the form an instant to refresh. However, the progress bar is most likely animating the bar filling (It moves slowly across until it reaches the specified value). So it may take 2 seconds to reach the expected position, but only has an instant to refresh, causing it to appear broken. Using a background worker or thread with invoking would most likely correct the issue.

Comment: Thanks Wiz, that makes sense, I'll try some things.